# Php API Ajax Pagination

Tags: php, html, ajax, api

```
    <?php
$current_user = get_current_user_id();
$username = 'Micketo';
$password = 'fOh2 y5ho nAEQ qjby';

//Create the headers array.
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("$username:$password")
);

// Sending
$pf = curl_init();
curl_setopt($pf, CURLOPT_URL, "https://micxtech.com/wp-json/wp/v2/wallet/$current_user");
curl_setopt($pf, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($pf, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($pf, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
curl_setopt($pf, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL); 
curl_setopt($pf, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');

$response = curl_exec($pf);
if (curl_error($pf)) {
    die('Unable to connect: ' . curl_errno($pf) . ' - ' . curl_error($pf));
}
curl_close($pf);

// Decode response
$jsonData = json_decode($response, true);

// EDITED BELOW THIS LINE
$table .= <<<HTML
<table style="width:100%;margin-bottom:.1em;table-layout: fixed;overflow: hidden;display: block;margin-top: -0.4em">
    <tr class="trclass">
        <th class="thclass">REF.</th>
        <th class="thclass">Date</th>
        <th class="thclass">Typ</th>
        <th class="thclass">Amt(₦)</th>
        <th class="thclass">Bal(₦)</th>
        <th class="thclass">Desc.</th>
    </tr>
HTML;

foreach ($jsonData as $v)
{
    $table .= <<<HTML
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass" style="width:auto;max-width:5%;vertical-align:middle"><strong>{$v['transaction_id']}</strong></td>
        <td class="tdclass" style="width:auto;max-width:20%;vertical-align:middle">{$v['date']}</td>
        <td class="tdclass" style="width:auto;max-width:13%;vertical-align:middle">{$v['type']}</td>
        <td class="tdclass" style="width:auto;max-width:16%;vertical-align:middle">{$v['amount']}</td>
        <td class="tdclass" style="width:auto;max-width:16%;vertical-align:middle">{$v['balance']}</td>
        <td class="tdclass" style="width:auto;max-width:30%;vertical-align:middle">{$v['details']}</td>
    </tr>
HTML;
}
    
$table .= <<<HTML
</table>
HTML;
echo $table;
?>
```

Please how can I write a pagination for this API fetch code. Been trying to get it done all day, but couldn't.

What this code does is that, it list all the data in one page (almost 50 transactions of a particular user) which makes the page even slower.

Comment: My question is how can I write an ajax pagination for the data fetched from the server. I want to have 10 transactions per page, and also have it linked to the next page correctly.

Comment: You can use https://datatables.net